# Python groupby datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I know this is an ancient question and I have searched all previous posts but cannot quite find answers that address my specific question.

I am dealing with a dataframe that looks like this

```
   Date    Position  Value
2010-01-01 PEAK      600
2010-01-01 BOTTOM    510
2010-01-02 PEAK      620
2010-01-02 BOTTOM    500
...
2015-03-02 PEAK      700
```

which contains no nan values or weird characters. However, the original data is not of "date" format, so I converted it to "date" format using

```
df1 = df.sort('Date')
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
```

but after I tried to group my dataframe using groupby() command

```
df1.groupby('Date')
```

before grouping the "Position" column and performing calculation on "Value," I keep getting error message that shows

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f880d4f2160>
```

but nothing generated.

I was expecting my code would group all row entries with the same datetime value together, but this didn't turn out that way.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please accept if right! I love that juicy reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error. `groupby` returns a groupby object, which then you have to call an aggregating function on. Usually people call `.mean()` on it, tho there are others that maybe someone else can fill you in on.

Since I don't know exactly what you want, I'll take a guess with my example

```
 df1.groupby(['Date', 'Position']).mean()
```

Will output a dataframe grouped by date and position, with the PEAK and BOTTOM values averaged for all PEAK and BOTTOM values, respectively, for that particular day.

Oh wait there's only a peak and bottom value for a particular day. Try

```
df1[['Date', 'Value']].groupby('Date').mean()
```

That averages the values for that day.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks so much for your prompt reply. I need to read document more thoroughly though.

Comment: @ChrisT. Anytime!